# Spring 4 MVC redirect to external https server, the target host is being replaced by the local host

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redirect, thymeleaf

I'm having a strange behavior with my Spring 4 MVC external url redirection. My application can be accessed via both the http and https protocols. I'm trying to redirect to https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/xxxx?a=abc&b=bcd but for some reasons, the application is doing an internal redirection to https://my_host_here/r/xxxx?a=abc&b=bcd. The issue occurs only when my application is accessed via https prototol; that is, the external redirection is working perfectly to the url (https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/xxxx?a=abc&b=bcd) when my application is accessed via the http protocol.

I'm using Spring 4, and Thymeleaf 3.
This is how I'm doing the redirection in the controller:

```
return "redirect:"+ url;
```

Below is the configuration of my viewresolver

```
  <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    <property name="templateMode" value="HTML5" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="templateEngine"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver" />
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
    <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
  </bean>
```

I logged and verified that the url is  https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/xxxx?a=abc&b=bcd, and I do not believe that the url is the cause since as I mentioned, it is working fine when my application is accessed thru the http instead of https.

Comment: Where do you get the `url` variable from in `return "redirect:"+ url;` ?

Comment: I retrieved the url from a database (mysql 8), and assigned it to a field in a DTO object. Not sure if it will be helpful but this is the code:
`logger.debug(wrapper.getAssessUrl());
return "redirect:" + wrapper.getAssessUrl();`

Comment: If you open Chrome dev tools, you can set "Preserve log" in the Network tab to see what redirects are happening. Maybe that can help you debug what is happening.

Comment: The log shows that it is doing an internal redirect (to  https://my_host_here/r/xxxx?a=abc&b=bcd) instead of the external redirect (to https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/xxxx?a=abc&b=bcd)

Comment: Who puts the URL in the database? Is it an absolute URL or a relative URL?

Comment: A process within the application retrieved the url from Survey Monkey and fed the database. I double-checked the url in the database and log and I am confident that it is correct. As I stated before, the external redirect  to the same destination is working fine when  user accesses the application via http (http://my_host_server:8080/app/...) instead of https (https://my_host_server/app/...).